# Refresh the services and controllers after logging out

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to refresh the page (controllers and services) after logging out :

```
angular.module('ToDoManagerApp').controller('LogoutCtrl', function(authToken, $state, $window) {
    authToken.removeToken();
    $window.location.reload();
    $state.go('main');
});
```

Is there any solution to "merge" the refresh and the redirection in one call ? I'm using ui-router

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `reload` param in the `$state`

```
$state.go('main', {}, {reload: true});
```

Comment: It doesn't refresh the page unfortuneltly.

Comment: If you want to just refresh the page, do `window.location.reload(true)` @user3557384

Comment: I want to do both, i want to redirect to main while refreshing. In other words,  i want to refresh 'on' main.

Comment: @user3557384 -- Just do a `location.href = URLTOMAINHERE`

Comment: It still not refreshing nor redirecting. I tried :    $window.location.href = 'http://localhost:9000/#/';

Comment: Are you sure that code is even being hit? @user3557384

Comment: Yes, it is. Because my first solution is working, but it is a bit weird to reload and then redirect, that's why i was looking for another solution that does both in the same time.

Comment: Have you found a solution meanwhile? I have the same problem